# How to define external database url in api.py of django-tastypie?

Tags: database, resources, tastypie

I don't know how to define a url to my external database (a couch database) in the Resource. I have this:

class UserResource(Resource):

```
username=fields.CharField(attribute='username')
firstName=fields.CharField(attribute='firstName')
lastName=fields.CharField(attribute='lastName')
gender=fields.CharField(attribute='gender')
status=fields.IntegerField(attribute='status')
date=fields.DateTimeField(attribute='date')

class Meta:
    object_class = ??
    resource_name = 'users/list'
    always_return_data = True
    authorization= Authorization()

def get_object_list(self, request):
   ...            
       return results

def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):
   # Filtering disabled for brevity...
   return self.get_object_list(request)
```

Comment: Do you have models for the tables in the database?

Comment: Yes, and they have the same attributes that i defined above...

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserResource(ModeslResource)
    class Meta:
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all().using('dbname')
```